# Is there a language-independent name for the symbol between a Map key and value?

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax, programming-languages, associative-array

I.e. is there a generic name for the `:` in Groovy's `['a':'1']`, `=>` in Ruby's `{:a => '1'}`, `->` in Scala's `Map('a'->'1')`?

Comment: So far no affirmative answers, will leave open for a while then close with "doesn't exist".

Comment: I propose `maperator` or `mapinator`. Or `keybob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no universally accepted term for this symbol, although there are a few variants with some traction listed in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a specific word for it, but you could call it the "maps to" operator.

i.e: a `maps to` 1

Comment: And in mathematics it's written `|->`. http://jopsen.dk/downloads/GSoC2010/mapsto.png

Answer (score 1):

Well, the structure is [an associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), and the role is that of an assignment operator.  For a given language, the expression could be called the assignment token.

In general, though, I don't think there is a standard name, but the resulting data structures (associative arrays) and the types of operations (i.e. assignment) are pretty universal.  You may also take a look at [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28mapping%29) for a comparison across languages.